# redirect to another php page from the page which is call by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am doing a simple job. i am calling a ajax function like **call_ajax(file, container_id)** from the file just as **parent.php.**
which process the page **file** and get reponse to the desired **container_id**.
here file is file1.php.  now on file1.php is running successfully and get back response.

but the problem is that when i going through some checking just as login comfirm i have to redirect to the login page such as **login.php** from file1.php and stop transfer response to the **parent.php.**

i am using header function of php to transfer but yes it transfer and get response as login page in the container id. I know that its correct as by ajax behaviour what ever target file get content return as response. but what is the solution of my problem. i would not like found my login page in container_id and want to load login page from file1.php.

Comment: What if check first if the user accessing that page was logged in before executing that ajax request.

Comment: yes.but the session is expired by some reason. such as user has open the page in another tab and logged out from there. but the current page is opened and ready to ajax call.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: Make a login validation in the page where the ajax will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont really know how you did your pages but for me i would use a meta tag. It best used if the person is not logged in and access the page . this is the code i used. So place this in your php coding so when ajax calls the files it will run through the php files and when it hits this line it will "refresh" another page and exit the main one

```
             echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=Login.php">';    
                exit;
```

The person will be redirected immediately. And if you can Please Post your codes!

Comment: yes i have check it but brother i want to redirect from the php page which is calling by ajax. i can't place checking in ajax script.

Comment: do a condition and place this inside the php code. I am sorry if this was not helpfull

Comment: yes i had put it but not performing. if you understand my problem please find the solution. i will be very thankful to you. i am also finding the solution at my end

Comment: I will See if i have time due to the fact i have not done php in month so my memory is not fresh

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Some thing like this to Change your location with in an ajax call.

echo "script  top.location='login.php'; script ";
exit;

Comment: i am not loading the page from ajax script instead i want to loading from target page through php